# Issue in png image when exporting SSRS report to PDF format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an issue in PDF exporting functionality in SSRS report.The report contains a PNG image with several lines.When I preview the report in browser(Both IE and Chrome) that image is displaying correctly but when I exported it to the PDF and open the file in PDF viewer software, the lines inside the image are getting blurry.

The image is loaded to a standard image control in SSRS report.I already have tried all the image size properties inside the image controller(like Original Size / Fit to size etc) and   images with different resolutions, but still the issue is there. Please note that I can't change the image format from PNG to other one since I want to keep the image background as transparent.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a number of things. Sometimes the image is fine but your screen resolution and the PDF viewer combined can make them look bad.

First, try to print the PDF and see if if still looks bad, if it looks OK printed then the chances are it's the screen resolution and/or PDF viewer causing it. I use Nitro PDF and they always look better than using Adobe Reader.

In anyway case, savingthe PNG with  higher DPI setting will usually fix the issue. Typically I save PNG's at 600 dpi, which might be overkill but it does mean they are sharp on the PDF.

If you need a Windows tool to save at a different DPI, try Inkscape which is free. When you export images you can set the DPI to whatever you want. Try 600dpi and if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I have checked with the printouts but the issue was still there. Also I have tried with higher resolution images like 1200 * 800 but couldn't observe any improvement and changing the PDF viewer from Adobe to Nitro is not a solution for us since this is a client specific report and we can't ask the client to change the software. Any other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: It's the DPI of the image that's important, not the  resolution. Try saving it at 600dpi

Comment: Yes, I have set the set the DPI as 600 but couldn't find any improvement.

Comment: Do you have a sample image and/or rdl file I can look at. Also what size is the image set on the report? I will try to reproduce your report and maybe send you an image I typically use.

Comment: Thanks Alan, but here it's not allowed me to upload an image.How can I share an image with you? Shall I put it in google drive or somewhere?

Comment: That's fine, send as much relevant stuff as you have and I'll take a look

Comment: Hi Alan, Please look at those two images in the below path. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZY_Hrs8Jfa8x3k4KXq_v8WvuSVoHhwks?usp=sharing

Comment: Do yo have the original file that your report uses? I assume the files you sent are screen grabs?

Comment: No, those images are generating dynamically at the run time and no any original image files, but you could try with the image in the below link. https://www.google.lk/search?q=png+images+lines&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHqvW5l9jeAhUGeisKHZVEAz8QsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1442&bih=786&dpr=1#imgrc=dYAXG5WuccyH-M:

Comment: AH I see. I wasn't aware that the images were being generated.Maybe update your question and explain how you generate them, as that might be where the issue lies.